# .NET stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I am having trouble creating a stored procedure.

This should work but it doesn't return a value.

I can create the static SQL statement from the application code before I call the stored procedure.

How would I pass the SQL statement to the stored procedure? It would be a string.

```
USE [DBNAME]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLocationIDValue]
     @returncolumn as nvarchar(50) OUTPUT,
     @locationid as int,
     @handle as varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT ' + @returncolumn + ' 
     FROM Location 
     WHERE locationkey = @locationid 
       AND ClientHandle = @handle
END
```

Comment: You need to build your SQL statement as a string in a varchar variable, and then execute it as dynamic sql via call to EXEC. But for oneliner SELECT statements you don't need to create a full blown SP. Create a parametrized query in your .NET code instead

Comment: `OUTPUT` returns scalars, `SELECT` returns tables. Which are you trying to do?

Comment: You need @returnColumn from SP right? For that you can directly use SELECT statement.

Comment: This is a query that will be run to return one record and could be ran 1000 times during one page load so moving it to a SP seems to fix timeout and pool issues.

Comment: So I have a function that you call and provide the 3 variables.  It then returns a result.   Basically I need a way to query a column in a table but not specify the SQL statement directly.  I can do this with normal .NET SQL but not with a stored procedure.  The issue is it uses too many resources in the application pool and fails.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to get back different columns each time you call this.  Is that correct?  If so, why are you getting it back a column at a time?  Why do you need different columns every time?  This feels like an XY problem where you really have a performance problem but are asking how to fix this strange (at least to me) way of solving the original problem.

Comment: Yes it seems its a XY problem, please post your actual requirement here. For more about XY problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Well I can fix the original problem but it will require 10000 lines of code where this would allow for 20.

I just want to be able to pass the dynamically created SQL statement to a stored procedure from the Code Behind.  Is that not possible?

Comment: can you post your original code that you say is timing out? there could be something else wrong with it.